# Regular Expression to get text from css

Tags: php, javascript, css, regex, string

I have css that which follows..

```
<style>
.body{
    width:2px;
    height:3px;
    }
</style>
<style>
.anotherOne{
    key:value;
    ...........
    }
</style>
```

and the HTML part

```
<div class="body"></div>
```

So how can i get the value inside the 'body' class on first style tag ? also i want to append data there,how can i do with this javascript and regular expressions ??
is there any other way ?

I want to get anything inside that starting with `".body{" and ending with "}"`

Edit :the expected result is `width:2px;
        height:3px;`

Comment: What is it that you're trying to accomplish? I don't think regexp are the suitable solution for this

Comment: I have a string that contain html data,i want to get the value inside curly bracket that start with `body` selector.

Comment: Where is this CSS?  In your web page as parsed CSS styles?  In a javascript dtring?

Comment: Is this for PHP or for Javascript? (Please don't tag-spam.)

Comment: Do you want to do this server-side (php) or client-side (javascript)?

Comment: the string contain CSS and HTML parts it will be like this `var n ;n="<html><head><style>
    .body{
    width:2px;
    height:3px;
    }
   
</style><style>
.anotherOne{
key:value;
...........
}
</style>
</head><body><div class="body"></div></body></html>"`

Comment: @mario ,both are accepted ,Javascript is my first priority.

Comment: What you are really trying to do is unclear, maybe another solution might be better. Changing CSS on the fly using javascript is unheard of, kind of cryptic!

Comment: Might there be a body class in a consecutive style tag?

Comment: @andho simple ! i have a string with some css & html content and  want to extract text from a particular section on that string.

Comment: @DileepDil: Don't use `[solved]` indicators in the title when you've got a good answer to your question. That's what the checkmark is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have CSS styles isolated in a javascript string, you can get the width value with this regex:

```
var re = /\.body\s*\{[^\}]*?width\s*:\s*(.*);/m;
var matches = str.match(re);
if (matches) {
    var width = matches[1];
}
```

Test case here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/jSDeJ/.

The height value can be obtained with this regex:

```
\.body\s*\{[^\}]*?height\s*:\s*(.*);/m;
```

If you just want the text (whatever it is that's inside the curly brackets for the body tag, then you can do that with this:

```
var re = /\.body\s*\{([^\}]*?)\}/m;
var matches = str.match(re);
if (matches) {
    var width = matches[1];
}
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/jSDeJ/3/

If you then want to replace the entire .body style with your own string, you can do that like this:

```
var str = " <style>\n.body{\n width:2px; \n height:3px; \n  } \n</style>"; 

var re = /(\.body\s*\{)([^\}]*?)(\})/m;
var newStyle = "width: 20px; \nheight: 1000px;";
var result = str.replace(re, "$1" + newStyle + "$3");
alert(result);
```

You can see that work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/jSDeJ/8/

Comment: I think you should constrain the regex to the style tag

Comment: I assumed he already had just styles in the string (much of this question is vague).  If not, then the OP can do that first.

Comment: it returns `2px` the expected one is `width:2px;
    height:3px;
`

Comment: This is a regex to get you the width value (just like my answer says in the first line).  I thought that's what you wanted.  You can modify the regex to make a second one to get you the height value by just changing "width" to "height".  There is no guarentee that width and height will be right next to each other so you should get them each separately.

Comment: From where u got `width` ?? i want values inside the scope,whatever it is.

Comment: i am sorry,i think that u are going too much,i just need the values as string,sometimes it will be `width` or `height`,its depended,we cant assume that,leave that part,just get text inside that curly brackets[at least now]

Comment: OK, I added an option to the end of my answer to get everything in between the curly brackets on the .body selector.

Comment: Cool,it worked.Thank you very much,Now i got the value from that curly brackets ,how can i replace that with my own one ?

Comment: Replacement example added at the end of my answer.

Comment: waav...its great..i combined some of your comments,and it works well now,also i want that `width` now,thanks for that.

Comment: it works well...but how can i remove that `"."` [DOT] from the beginning of the style tag so it will be `<style>body{key:value;}</style>` !

Comment: Sure, you can remove the dot if you want.  Just remove the slash before it too.

Comment: @jfriend00 Hai,it works well ,but i need to include the `<style>` tags too ,currently it getting data from `body` tags ,how can i include the `style` tag also ,so it will find data from the `<body>` tag of the first `<style>` tag...how it is possible ? thank you .

Answer (score 0):

This looks promising...

https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser

Or, if you just want to know the "computed value", I'd rely on the browser's parser and just extract the values with javascript DOM methods.

Hope that helps...