# javascript string replace with another value

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Hello there ,

```
var s = "width:20px;height:25px;color:red;font-family:myfontfamily";
```

i have a string like this,now how can i change the values of width,height etc using javascript.there may be  a `\n` after or before the properties (width,height etc)..

Ex : i want to change `width` to `50px` on `s`.
so it will be

```
var s = "width:50px;height:25px;color:red;font-family:myfontfamily";
```

My another replated Question is here [Regular Expression to get text from css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075256/regular-expression-to-get-text-from-css) but it not working exactly what i need.

Please help me.

Thank you.

`Update : You can see the Result on my fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/jitheshkt/s2DJR/14/`

Comment: Hi. Instead of working with straight CSS strings, why don't you use js built-in styles' modifiers ? Like `document.getElementById('thing').style.width = '50px';`

Comment: the string s is coming from a editor,not from a web page also i want to back data to that editor.also this is not a dom object,just string.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions.

For example:

```
s = s.replace(/color:\s*([^;]+)/, "color:" + newvalue)
```

Comment: Works well ,but i have a custom value there which is `background:url({background})` code breaks here...is there any way to avoid this...

Comment: Hi,check this `var s = "background-color:white;color:red;"
s = s.replace(/color:\s*([^;]+)/, "color:" + 'green');
    alert(s);` it replacing the `background-color` value...is there any way to override this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = "width:20px;\nheight:25px;\ncolor:red;\nfont-family:myfontfamily";

alert( s.replace(/width:\d+/,'width:123').replace(/height:\d+/,'height:456') );
```

Comment: Thank you ,but works with int values only,i am failed to change the color value.